# ANN in C "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'outputLayer' was corrupted." Error after running

Tags: c, neural-network, runtime-error

I wrote a neural network in C. There is a neuron model structure and input, hidden then output layer structures. This code was actually written in Python but I transformed it to C. After the debugging or running there is a error like that **"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'outputLayer' was corrupted."** The predicton output is correct but in the end the error occurred. Here is the code below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define INPUT_SIZE 3 
#define HIDDEN_SIZE 8
#define OUTPUT_SIZE 1
#define LEARNING_RATE 0.09
#define EPOCHS 20000



struct Neuron {
    double weights[INPUT_SIZE];

    double bias;
};

double relu(double x) {
    return fmax(0, x);
}

double sigmoid(double x) {
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x));
}

double sigmoid_derivative(double x) {
    return x * (1 - x);
}

double calculateNeuronOutput(struct Neuron *neuron, double inputs[], int use_relu) {

    double sum = neuron->bias;
    for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE; i++) {
        sum += inputs[i] * neuron->weights[i];
    }
    
    if (use_relu){
        return relu(sum);
    }
    else {
        return sigmoid(sum);
    }

}
void backPropagation(struct Neuron inputLayer[], struct Neuron hiddenLayer[], 
                          struct Neuron outputLayer[], double inputVector[], double target) {

    double hiddenLayerOutput[HIDDEN_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < HIDDEN_SIZE; i++) {
        hiddenLayerOutput[i] = calculateNeuronOutput(&hiddenLayer[i], inputVector, 1);
    }

    double output = calculateNeuronOutput(&outputLayer[0], hiddenLayerOutput, 0);

    double error = 0.5 * pow(target - output, 2);

    double output_error = target - output;
    double output_delta = output_error * sigmoid_derivative(output);

    double hiddenLayer_error[HIDDEN_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < HIDDEN_SIZE; i++) {
        hiddenLayer_error[i] = output_delta * outputLayer[0].weights[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < HIDDEN_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < INPUT_SIZE; j++) {
            hiddenLayer[i].weights[j] += LEARNING_RATE * hiddenLayer_error[i] * inputVector[j];

        }
        hiddenLayer[i].bias += LEARNING_RATE * hiddenLayer_error[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < OUTPUT_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < HIDDEN_SIZE; j++) {
            outputLayer[i].weights[j] += LEARNING_RATE * output_delta * hiddenLayerOutput[j];
        }
        outputLayer[i].bias += LEARNING_RATE * output_delta;
    }
}


int main() {
        
    struct Neuron inputLayer[INPUT_SIZE] = {
        {{0.1, -0.2, 0.3}, 0.1},
        {{0.2, -0.1, -0.3}, 0.2},
        {{0.3, 0.4, -0.1}, 0.2},
    };

    struct Neuron hiddenLayer[HIDDEN_SIZE] = {
        {{0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, 0.1},
        {{0.2, 0.1, -0.3}, 0.2},
        {{0.3, 0.4, 0.1}, 0.3},
        {{0.2, 0.1, 0.4}, -0.4},
        {{0.5, 0.2, -0.3}, -0.1},
        {{0.1, 0.3, 0.2}, 0.4},
        {{0.3, -0.4, 0.1}, 0.2},
        {{0.4, 0.2, -0.1}, -0.3}

    };

    struct Neuron outputLayer[OUTPUT_SIZE] = {
        {{0.1, -0.2, 0.3}, 0.2}

    };
    
    double inputVector[4][INPUT_SIZE] = { { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 },{0.0, 1.0, 0.0},{0.0, 1.0, 1.0},{1.0, 1.0, 1.0 } };
    double targetOutput[4] = { {0.0},{1.0},{1.0},{0.0} };

    for (int epoch = 0; epoch < EPOCHS; epoch++) {

        for(int i=0; i< 4; i++){
            
            backPropagation(inputLayer, hiddenLayer, outputLayer, inputVector[i], targetOutput[i]);
        }
            

        if (epoch % 1000 == 0) {
            double totalError = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                double hiddenLayerOutput[HIDDEN_SIZE];
                for (int j = 0; j < HIDDEN_SIZE; j++) {
                    hiddenLayerOutput[j] = calculateNeuronOutput(&hiddenLayer[j], inputVector[i], 1);
                }
                double output = calculateNeuronOutput(&outputLayer[0], hiddenLayerOutput, 0);

                double error = 0.5 * pow(targetOutput[i] - output, 2);
                totalError += error;

            }
            printf("Epoch: %d, Loss: %f\n", epoch, totalError);
        }
    }
    
    // Tahmin 

    double predictionInput[4][INPUT_SIZE] = { { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 },{0.0, 0.0, 1.0},{0.0, 1.0, 1.0},{0.0, 1.0, 1.0 } };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        double hiddenLayerOutput[HIDDEN_SIZE];
        for (int j = 0; j < HIDDEN_SIZE; ++j) {
            hiddenLayerOutput[j] = calculateNeuronOutput(&hiddenLayer[j], predictionInput[i], 1);
        }

        double finalOutput = calculateNeuronOutput(&outputLayer[0],hiddenLayerOutput, 0);

        printf("Input: (%f, %f, %f), Exact Output: %f, Predicton: %f\n",
            predictionInput[i][0], predictionInput[i][1], predictionInput[i][2], targetOutput[i], finalOutput);
    }

    return 0;
```

}

I can get a output which is below but in the last line I got this error.

```
{Epoch: 0, Loss: 0.526654
Epoch: 1000, Loss: 0.003173
Epoch: 2000, Loss: 0.001147
Epoch: 3000, Loss: 0.000665
Epoch: 4000, Loss: 0.000458
Epoch: 5000, Loss: 0.000346
Epoch: 6000, Loss: 0.000275
Epoch: 7000, Loss: 0.000228
Epoch: 8000, Loss: 0.000194
Epoch: 9000, Loss: 0.000168
Epoch: 10000, Loss: 0.000148
Epoch: 11000, Loss: 0.000132
Epoch: 12000, Loss: 0.000119
Epoch: 13000, Loss: 0.000108
Epoch: 14000, Loss: 0.000099
Epoch: 15000, Loss: 0.000091
Epoch: 16000, Loss: 0.000085
Epoch: 17000, Loss: 0.000079
Epoch: 18000, Loss: 0.000074
Epoch: 19000, Loss: 0.000069
Input: (0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000), Act Output: 0.000000, Prediction: 0.006382
Input: (0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000), Act Output: 1.000000, Prediction: 0.999901
Input: (0.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000), Act Output: 1.000000, Prediction: 0.992201
Input: (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000), Act Output: 0.000000, Prediction: 0.005400 }
```

And this is the error: `{Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'outputLayer' was corrupted.}`

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Your `weights[]` array has size 3, but you index it up to `HIDDEN_SIZE - 1` in `backPropagation()`.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I don't understand what you mean, can you show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least this, in `backPropagation()`:

```c
    double hiddenLayer_error[HIDDEN_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < HIDDEN_SIZE; i++) {
        hiddenLayer_error[i] = output_delta * outputLayer[0].weights[i];
    }
```

`outputLayer[0].weights[]` is an array of size 3.

Your loop indexes that array from 0 to 7, which will cause undefined behaviour.

You have the same problem in this code:

```c
    for (int i = 0; i < OUTPUT_SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < HIDDEN_SIZE; j++) {
            outputLayer[i].weights[j] += LEARNING_RATE * output_delta * hiddenLayerOutput[j];
        }
        outputLayer[i].bias += LEARNING_RATE * output_delta;
    }
```

Comment: Oh, Im an idiot. I got the point and fix it like that outputLayer[0].weights[i%3];
but if there any solution for this I would really like to hear it. Thanks for your help. Im gonna try to fix them all.